# The sum of multiplicities of two singular points of an irreducible curve of degree n is at most n.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Prove

1. that the sum of multiplicities of two singular points of an irreducible curve of degree $n$ is at most $n$,
2. sum of multiplicities of any 5 points is at most $2n$.

I tried to use Bezuot theorem.

1. Let $P$ and $Q$ are points with multiplicities $p<n$ and $q<n$, then the line $L$ intersects the curve $C$ at least at $p+q < 2n$. As  the curve C is irreducible, this number is $n$.
2. I guess The Bezuot theorem is useful here but I have no idea how to applay it.

Could someone check the first proof and correct it if it's wrong and give me idea how to prove the second?

Comment: Given 5 points there is exactly one conic passing through them, [see wikipedia for example.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic)

Comment: @yamete kudasai.: Thank you for your hint. What about first part. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to consider the line passing through the points $P$ and $Q$. But it is not relevant to add the equations $p<n$ and $q<n$. You just have to emphasize that the multiplicity of intersection of two curves is always bigger or equal than the multiplicity of the point together with the fact that the multiplicities of intersection add to $n$ by Bezout theorem.

Comment: @yametekudasai Forgive me but I have the same question, and I am slightly confused. Could you please elaborate if possible?